# Insert a blank line in fasta file

Tags: r, fasta

I want to read a fasta file that contain multiple dna sequences, transcript it to rna and write the result in a fasta format, here is the code :

```
library("Biostrings")
dna <- readDNAStringSet("D:/R/smpl.fasta")
rna <- RNAStringSet(complement(dna))
rna
```

I get :

```
  A RNAStringSet instance of length 2
    width seq                           names               
[1]   742 GGCGGGGAGACGG...CAAAAGUCUUUAU gi|568815581:4168...
[2]   910 CACGGUCGACACA...UCUCGAGUUUCUC gi|568815581:4168...
```

And i wrote it in a file by typing:

```
write.fasta(sequences = as.list(rna), names = names(rna), nbchar = 60, file.out = "D:/R/rna.fasta")
```

The result (`rna.fasta`) :

```
>gi|568815581:41688875-41691646 Homo sapiens chromosome 17, GRCh38.p2 Primary Assembly
GGCGGGGAGACGGGGUC...
>gi|568815581:41688875-41691646 Homo sapiens chromosome 18, GRCh38.p2 Primary Assembly
CACGGUCGACACAACAU...
```

How can i add a blank line after the end of each sequence ? To have as result :

```
>gi|568815581:41688875-41691646 Homo sapiens chromosome 17, GRCh38.p2 Primary Assembly
GGCGGGGAGACGGGGUC...

>gi|568815581:41688875-41691646 Homo sapiens chromosome 18, GRCh38.p2 Primary Assembly
CACGGUCGACACAACAU...
```

Comment: Do you have to have the output in fasta?  Or is a plain text file OK?  Also, which `write.fasta` function are you using?  There are versions in different packages, but not in `Biostrings`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does what you want, except that the "blank" lines start with `>` and are followed with a blank line.  I don't think you can avoid this if using `write.fasta`.

```
# Example data from documentation
library("Biostrings")
filepath <- system.file("extdata", "someORF.fa", package="Biostrings")
dna <- readDNAStringSet(filepath)
rna <- RNAStringSet(complement(dna))

# Create a emtpy list to hold the results
rna_out <- vector("list", length(rna)*2)
use <- (1:length(rna_out)) %% 2 # the elements to which we'll put data
cnt <- 1 # separate counter into rna_out

# Fill the list
for (i in 1:length(rna_out)) {
    if (as.logical(use[i])) {
        rna_out[i] <- as.character(rna[cnt])
        names(rna_out)[i] <- names(rna)[cnt]
        cnt <- cnt + 1}
    if (!as.logical(use[i])) {
        rna_out[i] <- ""
        names(rna_out)[i] <- ""
        }
    }

library("seqinr") # need the write.fasta from this pkg
write.fasta(rna_out, names = names(rna_out), file.out = "rna.txt")
```

If you don't want it that way, I have a version that writes plain text with the same information, but no `>`.  I guess it depends upon why you want those blank lines.